# Input tag in html not sending POST variable upon adding onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This works ..

```
<form name="form1" action="test.php" method="post">
table class="questiontable" border="0">
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="previous_question" id="previous_question" value="Previous Question"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
echo $_POST["previous_question"] ;
?>
```

Output

```
Previous Question
```

However this does not work and gives blank output. (the please wait and disabling of the button works)

```
<form name="form1" action="test.php" method="post">
<table class="questiontable" border="0">
<tr><td><input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Please Wait...'; this.form.submit();" name="previous_question" id="previous_question" value="Previous Question"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
echo $_POST["previous_question"] ;
?>
```

I need that please wait on clicking to prevent the user from clicking twice. The problem is that the POST variable does not pass when this is done. I need that POST variable to check which submit button was pressed as my form has many.

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: there's a typo in your `table` opening tag

Comment: Disabled input is not included in a form when you send it

Comment: Disabled form fields are simply not valid for submission. Use readonly instead of disabled, or use a hidden field to submit the actual name=value pair, so that the disabled submit button becomes irrelevant.

Comment: You can write a function when you submit your form first and only after that you set your input to be disabled

Comment: try something `this.submit();`

Comment: @JavaEvgen Yes you are right, when I made readonly its working. Thanks a  lot.

Comment: @JavaEvgen When I put readonly upon clicking the value changes to 'Please Wait ..' but the CSS for input:read-only (which i copied from input;disabled) doesnt take effect. The form submits fine and the POST variable also received. Any ideas to get that CSS

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function foo () {
    getElementByName("previous_question").value("please wait...");
    getElementByName("form1").submit();
    getElementByName("previous_question").disabled = true;
}
```

And then call this function using your `onclick`

Comment: Yeah this also works, but the input:disabled CSS does not take effect.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form name="form1" action="test1.php" method="post">
<table class="questiontable" border="0">
<tr><td><input type="submit" onclick="send()" name="previous_question" id="previous_question" value="Previous Question"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<script>
function send(){
    this.disabled=true; 
    this.value='Please Wait...'; 
    this.form.submit();
}
</script>
<?php
echo $_POST["previous_question"] ;
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, by function it works, but the CSS for input:disabled is not applied once clicked.

Comment: yes because it's so fast that, you can't see it, you can use settimeout for this.

Comment: In the original code I could see the disabled CSS because its actually very very slow, its over the internet. Any ideas for the CSS ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="form1" action="test.php" method="post" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); submitnow();">
   <table class="questiontable" border="0">
     <tr><td><input type="submit" name="previous_question" id="previous_question" value="Previous Question"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitnow(){
    var id = document.getElementById('previous_question');
    id.disabled = true;
    id.value = 'Please Wait...';
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.form1.submit();
        id.disabled = false;
        id.value = 'Previous Question';
    }, 2000);
}
</script>
```